# Change jQuery Tabs from DropDownList's onchange-event

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

how to select a jQuery Tab onchange of an ASP.Net DropDownList according to the selected value?

Comment: Changed the title and the question to be more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
$("#dropdownClientIDHere").change(function()
    { 
        onDropdownChange(this.selectedIndex); 
    }); 

function onDropdownChange(index)
{
    $('#tabsElement').tabs("select" , index);
}
```

*(disclaimer - not tested)*

It'll select the tab matching the index of the selected item in the drop down list.

Also worth checking out the [jQuery ui tabs documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/). The method you'll want to look at is `select` as used here.